# Passing  array to function of shell script

Tags: shell

How to pass array as function in shell script?
I written following code:

```
function test(){
param1 = $1
param2 = $2
for i in ${$param1[@]}
do
   for j in ${param2[@]}
do
       if($(i) = $(j) )
           then
           echo $(i)
           echo $(j)
       fi
done
done
}
```

but I am getting `line 1: ${$(param1)[@]}: bad substitution`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- you can't have spaces around the `=` when assigning variables
- your if statement has the wrong syntax
- array passing isn't right
- try not to call your function `test` because that is a shell command

Here is the fixed version:

```
myFunction(){
  param1=("${!1}")
  param2=("${!2}")
  for i in ${param1[@]}
  do
    for j in ${param2[@]}
    do
       if [ "${i}" == "${j}" ]
       then
           echo ${i}
           echo ${j}
       fi
    done
  done
}

a=(foo bar baz)
b=(foo bar qux)
myFunction a[@] b[@]
```

Comment: it is working but it is not looping . param1 only contains first index for array . 
param1[0]

Comment: I am calling as 
myFunction $p1 $p2 
where $p1 size is 65

Comment: @vivek-goel i've updated my answer and added an example function call.

Comment: a=(foo bar baz)
b=(foo bar qux)
myFunction a[@] b[@]
gives me a[@] as o/p if I echo i. 
currently I am using as 

argument=`echo ${a[@]}`
this method is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script accordingly

```
#!/bin/bash

param[0]=$1
param[1]=$2


function print_array  {
        array_name=$1
        eval echo \${$array_name[*]}
        return
}

print_array param
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**A simple way :**

```
function iterate 
{
  n=${#detective[@]}
  for (( i=0; i<n; i++ ))
  do
    echo ${detective[$i]}
  done
}

detective=("Feluda" "Sharlockhomes" "Bomkesh" )
iterate ${detective[@]}
```