# In zsh pass hash as parameter

Tags: zsh

What is the correct / idiomatic way of passing a hash to a function?

I have sort of hit upon this but am not sure how clean this is or if there any pitfalls.

```
typeset -A hash
hash=(a sometext b moretext)

foo hash

foo() {
  typeset -A mhash
  mhash=( ${(Pkv)1} )
}
```

The P flag interprets result (in this case $1 as holding a parameter name). Since this resulted in only getting the values and not the keys, I bolted on the "kv" to get both keys and values.

Is this the correct way, or is there another way. btw, since i am passing an array and a hash in my actual program, I don't want to use "$*" or "$@"

Answer (score 1):

I tried a little and i'm not sure there is an other way than using $@ on the function.

[Re: Array as parameter - Zsh mailing list](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2011/msg00870.html)

Possible answers in these questions (bash-oriented):
[How to pass an associative array as argument to a function in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069188/how-to-pass-an-associative-array-as-argument-to-a-function-in-bash)
[Passing arrays as parameters in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063347/passing-arrays-as-parameters-in-bash)
[Passing  array to function of shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533364/passing-array-to-function-of-shell-script)

In fact, when you start needing to use an array, or even worse, an associative array in a shell script, maybe it's time to switch to a more powerful script language, like perl or python.
If you don't do it for you, do it for you 6 months from now / for your successors.