# Iterate through array given as argument to function in shell script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, for-loop

I'm having issues with iterating through an array passed as an argument to a function in my bash script. I thought the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533364/passing-array-to-function-of-shell-script) would solve my issue, but I'm getting a different error and the question is very old, so I thought I should ask a new question.

I am trying to convert this code to a function, so I can pass different parameters:

```
EX='WT'
declare -a SCN=('fq1' 
'fq2'
'fq3' )

for i in "${SCN[@]}"; do
    echo $i
    echo $EX'_'$i
done
```

This prints

```
fq1
WT_fq1  
fq2  
WT_fq2  
fq3  
WT_fq3
```

What I have tried:

```
function myfx(){
echo $1
MYNOR=("${!2}")
for i in ${MYNOR[@]}; do
    echo $i
    echo $1'_'$i
done
}
myfx $EX $SCN[@]
```

Unfortunately, all I get from this is

```
WT
```

It doesn't seem to be executing the statements within the loop.

Comment: ! causes history substitution in bash scripts.

Comment: @ArifBurhan Not in this construct: `${!a}`. In it, it is an indirect reference [If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), it introduces a level of variable indirection.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the function working is to do this:

```
function myfx(){
    echo "\$1=$1 \$2=$2"
    b=$2'[@]'
    for i in "${!b}"; do
        echo "$i"
        echo "$1_$i"
    done
}

myfx "$EX" "SCN"
```

Note that the function is called with the value of `$EX` and a label `SCN`.

Inside the function that label is used to build an indirect token `b=$2'[@]'`.

Then, the indirect token is used to generate the list of values inside `SCN`.
Using the indirection of bash `${!b}`.

---

A little more complex option is to use only labels to call the function:

```
    function myfx(){
    echo "\$1=$1 \$2=$2"
    a=${!1}
    b=$2'[@]'
    for i in "${!b}"; do
        echo "$i"
        echo "${a}_$i"
    done
}

myfx "EX" "SCN"
```

The only added complexity is the need for indirection on `$EX`.

---

But probably the simplest of solutions is to pass all the arguments needed:

```
function myfx(){
    echo "\$1=$1 \$2=$2"
    a=$1; shift
    for i do
        echo "$i"
        echo "${a}_$i"
    done
}

myfx "$EX" "${SCN[@]}"
```

The simple `for i` will iterate over all arguments, which after the shift on the line above, will be all the values of `"${SCN[@]}"`.